# Question to generating function

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

This is the question/riddle:

> **Five people** who wear a red hat spread a gossip. In the **first hour**
>   every one of them tells the gossip to **one other person** not yet wearing
>   a red hat. The new insiders than immediately put on a red hat. This
>   trend repeats itself with the following rule: Every person tells the
>   gossip to **one other person in the first hour** he heard the gossip, and
>   to **nine other persons in the following hours**. Nobody removes his hat,
>   how many persons wear the red hat (heard the gossip) after n-hours?
>   Hint: use generating functions

My question is, how would I turn a question like this into a generating functions?
This is my attempt:
$(1+x)(1+x)(1+x)(1+x)(1+x)+(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7+x^8+x^9) \cdot n$

Five $(1 + x)$ representing the first five persons plus the nine new one's  multiplied by $n$.

But I doubt this is correct.

What is the good generating function to solve this question, and how to get it?

Comment: n has to be limited because of population size.  What is the largest n can be?

Comment: A person hears the gossip.  In the first hour he tells 1 person and in the second hour he tells 9 people and each succeding hour tells 9 more people.  Is that the correct understanding of the problem?

Comment: @WilliamElliot Yes, that's correct